# Lipschitz-Condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let:

$f(x)=|x|^\alpha$, where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in[a,b]$, $(\alpha \ge 1)$

and

$g(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$, where $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in[1,+\infty)$

I have to prove that $f$ and $g$ functions satisfy Lipschitz-Condition.

With the $f$, I went like:
$$||x|^\alpha-|y|^\alpha|\le||a|^\alpha-|b|^\alpha|$$
And now I am a bit clueless, since if $a$ and $b$ are both positive I can go like:
$$||a|^\alpha-|b|^\alpha|\le||a^\alpha|-|b^\alpha|\le|a^\alpha-b^\alpha|$$ And now since $b\ge a$, we have that 
$$|a^\alpha-b^\alpha|\le|b^\alpha|=b^\alpha$$
since $b$ positive number higher than $a$. What on the other hand means that for every $M=\lceil b^\alpha\rceil$ this function satisfies Lipschitz condition. But I do not know how to get to it, when one $a<0$ and $b>0$ or $a,b<0$.

With the $g$, I went like:

Assume that $x>y$

$$|(1+\frac{1}{x})^x-(1-\frac{1}{y})^y|\le|(\frac{x+1}{y})^x-(\frac{y+1}{y})^y|\le|\frac{(x+1)^x-(y+1)^y}{y^y})\le|(x+1)^x-(y+1)^y)|$$

And now I am stuck. Any help/clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding $|x|^a$: this is (globally) Lipshitz only for $a=1$. For $a>1$ you can only prove a local Lipshitz condition (e.g. on any bounded interval $[u,v]$). To convince yourself about this start with the (probably) easiest case $a=2$.

Comment: (in genal: if you already do know about derivatives then the mean value theorem makes this kind of task very easy).

Comment: @Thomas as it is said at the begining x is in bounded interval. I can do it for 2, 3 and any other "numerical" case. But not for global case. And unfortunetly I know derivatives, but I am not allowed to use them in that task.